# Know if a future is started

Tags: java, asynchronous, future

I'm using openejb and asynchronous EJBs. I have a lot of Futures and would like to know if one on the futures takes too much time (so i can trace it and finally cancel it). The problem is that to know since how long the future si running, I need to know when it starts.
The Future interface let me know if a Future is finished or cancelled, but if it's not, I can't know if it's running or waiting for a thread in the pool.
Is it possible to get the Future status (Running/Not started)?

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't seem as if `Future` allows this. You could always have the task add itself to a collection, then check the collection to see which tasks are running.

Comment: Yes but I'd like to have a generic solution

Comment: It seems this flag-like system is the only way to easily achieve this behavior. Your next option would be extending upon the `Future` interface to add the flag to each future. But this would require you to mess around with whichever executor you are currently using, in order to have the executor pass you an instance of your `Future` implementation containing the flag

Comment: Could you show the code where the tasks are created and the `Future` objects are being used? I'll attempt write an answer that fits your needs

Answer (score -1):

I believe your intent is 
1) Get the return value from submitted task using Future
2) If its taking too long , cancel it.

If this is correct - then why not use get with specifying timeout value.

Comment: Because the `Future` could be waiting on a thread from the pool to be freed. If you timed out after 5 seconds, there's still no way to determine whether the task was in progress and is taking too long, or if the task was still waiting on a thread

Comment: The timeout is not exactly what I want. get(timeout) will fail if the future is not terminated within the timeout, even if it's not started. What I want is to  know how long the thread has been running. Edit : Vince explained it better than me :)